# Regex expression for finding special numbers

Tags: c#, regex

I need help to write a regex expression to catch following cases:

`number*number` like `1242*1242` or `333*333`. Both side of `*` are the same number but they can have different length.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO! We appreciate shown effort when questions are asked. So, what have you tried yourself? =)

Comment: *Both are the same number but they can have different length.* How can that be possible?

Comment: I -think- the OP means that both sides of the `*` are always the same number, but the number itself can be of varying length, just as their example shows. =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would fix Ofer's answer:

```
\b(\d+)\*\1\b
```

The explanation:

```
\b - word boundary
( - start capturing group
\d+ - digits (one or more)
) - stop capturing group
\* - literal *
\1 - matches exactly what is captured by group 1
\b - word boundary
```

Comment: More elegant that first `\b` will be outside. I updated my answer.

Comment: Wooh. Double +1 if I could, for including the explanation. So rare.

Comment: @Ofer Zelig - agreed; this time no difference, but might be different with other characters in place of `*`.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

`(\d+)\*\1`

It guarantees that the right side is the same as the left side.

**EDIT**

To ensure no false positives (although I would argue if this should be an issue if programming correctly) use this version (slightly different than Eugene's, a little bit more elegant):

`\b(\d+)\*\1\b`

Comment: But it's not the same number!

Comment: Shai does have a point, though. It will give false positives.

Comment: It isn't, but using this regex on a list of mathematical expressions will yield incorrect results